# Bring Chrome tab to foreground from Devtools window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Opening devtools is [easy enough](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), but what if i'm lost in a sea of chrome windows and tabs? Is it possible to bring the attached chrome window/tab on to the screen from the Devtools window?

-note this only makes sense if you have devtools running on a separate window-

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think it's possible! I tried `window.focus()` and `window.open('#foobar', '_self')` but neither of those work. You can submit a feature request on https://crbug.com

Comment: Thanks, I will do some more digging before opening an issue though, they seem to have their hands full.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This one was bugging me. I knew there had to be some hack to make this possible. Of course, the solution is one of the first friends that we meet in JavaScript land.

Open up the DevTools Console and type:

```
alert('show me');
```

Another workflow mentioned by [@morgunkorn on Twitter](https://twitter.com/morgunkorn/status/860506055092187136) is to press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (use <kbd>Control</kbd> instead of <kbd>Command</kbd> on Windows / Linux) to dock the DevTools window, which brings the tab to focus, and then press that combo again to return DevTools to its undocked setup.

Comment: It does the trick! I hope they add some shortcut to achieve this functionality. Thanks for your answer, i was starting to feel hopeless after i got no answers to what i thought was a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this tiny Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/go-to-set-tab/gahnefhpekegjhmplnmgpfcaebipbhne). This allows you to *set* a particular tab using the keyboard command `Alt + S`. You can switch back to that *set* tab anytime using the keyboard command `AlT + G`, even from the undocked devtool window.

Comment: thanks, but it is often that you have more than one window open, the extension seems to be limited to one tab at a time, also would it work when Alt + G is pressed in Devtools? Devtools itself uses it's own shortcuts and event listeners can differ from the regurlar chrome browser window.

Answer (score 0):

There now is a command called "Focus debuggee", that is also listed under the 3-dots settings drop-menu in top right corner. Another bonus is you can add a keyboard shortcut for it, if you find yourself losing the tab a lot like I do!